# Discrete Math- Function of sets.

Tags: functions, discrete-mathematics

$f: \{0, 1\}^* \to \mathbb{N}$, where $f(x) = k$ if the length of the string is $k$.

Can someone translate this for me, I do not quite understand what the star means at the end of the $\{0,1\}^*$.

Comment: Welcome to stackexchange. This is a reasonable question and I've provided an answer, but in the future you should post the mathematics using mathjax, not links to an image. https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Answer (score 2):

If $A$ is a set of symbols then $A^*$ is the set of all strings (words, sequences) built from elements of $A$. So $\{0,1\}^*$ is the set of all bit strings, like $1001$ and $10101000$.

Comment: or $001001110$ (just so OP doesn't get any wrong ideas)